# How to dynamically call a C function from Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm working on binding a library with a really bad structure - it has a bunch of functions named something like: <blah>_create(), and they all create a apriltag_family_t pointer.
How can I dynamically call <blah>_create() from Cython if I have a string which corresponds to the <blah> part?

Comment: I'd normally use ctypes, but that sort of defies the purpose of cython. Don't know too much about the latter, but my approach would be a dictionary of names-to-functions. This *must* be static though.

Comment: If you are in Linux or OS X, look at the dlsym() documentation.  If you are in Windows, look at the GetProcAddress() documentation.  They both can take a string which is the name of a C function and return a pointer to that function.  Be aware that sometimes this functionality requires special compiler or linker flags to work.